# Spring Boot Microservices - Design of API to get the response as a List by passing Ids

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I am using **Spring Boot and Spring Cloud for Microservices architecture** and using various things like API Gateway, Distributed Config, Zipkin + Sleuth, Cloud and 12 factor methodologies where we've single DB server has the same schema but tables are private.

Now I am looking to have below things - **Note - Response Object is nested and gives data in hierarchy.**

1. Can we ask downstream system to develop API to accept List of CustomerId and given response in one go?
2. Or can we simply call the same API multiple times giving single CustomerId and get the response?

Please suggest having complex response set and also having simple response set. What would be better considering performance and microservices in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option 1. This may be less RESTful but it is more performant, especially if the list of `CustomerId` is large. Following standards is for sure good, but sometimes the use case requires us to bend a bit the standards so that the system is useful.

With option 2. you will most probably "waste" more time with HTTP connection "dance" than with your actual use case of getting the data. Imagine having to call 50 times the same downstream service if you are required to retrieve the data from 50 `CustomerId`s.